# How to strip string down to "point guard"

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science

I'm trying to scrape the position off of [this](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/y/youngtr01.html) webpage using BeautifulSoup. Here is my relevant code.

```
info_panel = soup.find("div",{"id":"meta"})
info_panel_rows = info_panel.find_all("p")
if(info_panel_rows[2].find("strong") != None):
        position = info_panel_rows[2].find("strong").next_sibling
        position = str(position).strip()
else: # Executing on this path in my current problem
        position = info_panel_rows[3].find("strong").next_sibling 
        position = str(position).strip()
print(position)
```

When I scrape it though, it prints like such:

```
Small Forward



  ▪
```

How would I go about stripping this down to just "Small Forward"? I've looked all over Stack Overflow and couldn't find a clear answer.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: The source code and css style of that page is a disaster and I highly doubt that you can extract anything valuable or accurate from it. Search for a different source.

Comment: Please share the relevant part(s) of the HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having issues with newline and tab in position? if so, do

```
position = str(position).strip('\n\t ')
```

and if that dot is also an issue, copy from print and paste it into strip. when you dont put anything in strip, it only removes white space from both side, you need to specify what you want to remove, the above example removes newline and tab and whitespace

If this does not solve your problem, you can try regex

```
import re 
string_patterns = re.compile(r'\b[0-9a-zA-Z]*\b')
position = info_panel_rows[3].find("strong").next_sibling
results = string_patterns.findall(str(position))
results = ' '.join([item for item in results if len(item)])
print(results)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you encode it to ascii ignoring errors then call strip() you get the desired output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/y/youngtr01.html').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
info_panel = soup.find("div", {"id": "meta"})
info_panel_rows = info_panel.find_all("p")
if info_panel_rows[2].find("strong") is not None:
    position = info_panel_rows[2].find("strong").next_sibling
else:
    position = info_panel_rows[3].find("strong").next_sibling
print(position.encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip())
```

Outputs:

```
Point Guard
```

Encoding to ascii gets rid of the bullet point.

Or if you just want to print the second line:

```
print(position.splitlines()[1].strip())
```

Also outputs:

```
Point Guard
```